# Inequality with $x,y,z\geq 0$, $x+y+z=1.$

Tags: inequality

With $x,y,z\geq 0$, $x+y+z=1$.Prove that $$\sqrt{x+y^2}+\sqrt{y+z^2}+\sqrt{z+x^2}\geq 2 \tag{i}$$

The hint is using a lemma: 
If $a,b,c,d\geq 0 $satisfying $a+b=c+d$ and$|a-b|\leqslant|c-d|$ then we have $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\geq \sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$
How to prove this lemma? And is there a different way to prove the inequality (i)?

Comment: Which inequality we need to prove?

Comment: I think by Karamata if $\{a,b,c,d\}\subset[0,\infty)$, $a+b=c+d$ and $|a-b|\geq|c-d|$ so $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\leq\sqrt{c}+\sqrt{d}$.

Comment: The inequality $(i)$

Comment: If you have another solution , please post it

Comment: `The inequality (i)` There is no inequality in what you posted as $(i)$. That's just a sum of radicals.

Comment: Well, i named it as (i)

Comment: The first line ends with `Prove that ...` followed by a sum of radicals. Prove that *what*?

Comment: Sorry, i made a typo

Answer (score 2):

There is the following Vo Quoc Ba Can's solution.

We need to prove that 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\sqrt{x+y^2}-y\right)\geq1$$ or
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+y^2}+y}\geq1.$$
Now, by AM-GM 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+y^2}+y}=\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x(x+y)}{(x+y)\sqrt{x+y^2}+y(x+y)}\geq\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x(x+y)}{\frac{1}{2}((x+y)^2+x+y^2)+y(x+y)}.$$
Thus, it remains to prove that 
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{x(x+y)}{2x^2+4y^2+5xy+xz}\geq\frac{1}{2},$$
which is $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(4x^4y^2+16x^4yz+3x^3y^2z-19x^3z^2y-4x^2y^2z^2)\geq0,$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: For the less inequality-minded amongst us, why is the last line obvious?

Comment: @anthonyquas It is obvious by noticing that $$\sum_{cyc}(4x^4y^2+16x^4yz+3x^3y^2z-19x^3z^2y-4x^2y^2z^2)\equiv4\sum_{cyc}{y^2z^2(x-y)^2}+\frac{4xyz\sum_{cyc}{(2x^2+3yz+5xz+2y^2+3xy)(x-y)^2}}{x+y+z}$$

Comment: So I agree it is more or less obvious if you can convince yourself of the equality you wrote down!